# (XSL 2.0) Transform/Replace HTML and ASCII Characters in String

Tags: html, xml, xslt, ascii

I am editing an XSL Stylesheet to transform an XML document into a styled RTF file and I have some HTML code and ASCII characters in a string that I would like to replace with the equivalent text characters. I have been searching for an answer to this one, but haven't been able to find a solution that works. This is my first time working with XLS, so I really appreciate any help you can give!

For example, I have the below XML, translated from a CSV through Oxygen Editor

```
<root>
<row>    
<first_name>Joe</first_name>
<last_name>Smith</last_name>
<classnote>Joe Smith &amp;#39;62 sent a text to his friend‰Ûªs phone &lt;br /></classnote>
</row>
</root>
```

I would like to replace all instances of "&#39;" and "‰Ûª" with a right single quotation and replace all HTML breaks with a space.

I have tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&amp;#39;', '’')" />
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#39;', '’')" />
```

to replace "&#39;", and similar code to replace the line breaks.

Is there something simple I am missing here? I really appreciate the help. The full XSL is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="macroman" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template name="row">
    <xsl:text>{\pard \s2 \ql \f22\fs24 \li0\ri0\sb240\sl-360\slmult0</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>{\cs11 \b </xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="first_name" select="normalize-space(first_name)" />
    <xsl:variable name="last_name" select="normalize-space(last_name)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$first_name" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $last_name)" />
    <xsl:value-of
         select="if ( normalize-space(SVP) ) 
         then concat(' ', normalize-space(replace(SVP, '''', '’')), ',') 
         else ''" />
    <xsl:call-template name="degrees" />
    <xsl:text>} </xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="replace(classnote, '\s+', ' ')" />
    <xsl:value-of
         select="replace(replace(replace($temp, ' &quot;', ' “'), '&quot;', '”'), '''', '’')" />
    <xsl:text>\par}&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&amp;#39;', '’')" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you know about `replace` in XSLT/XPath 2.0 then why are you trying to use the `translate` function to replace sequences of characters? `translate` is useful to map a single character to a single character but if you want to replace a sequence of characters like `‰Ûª` with another string or character use `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

The context of the `classnote` element seems to be a string with an XML fragment so given Oxygen or any other environment having a commercial version of Saxon 9 it might be easiest to use XSLT 3.0 and `parse-xml-fragment` as then we can write a template to transform `br` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="classnote">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(.)" mode="convert"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br" mode="convert">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="convert">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&amp;#39;|‰Ûªs', '''')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the input being

```
<classnote>Joe Smith &amp;#39;62 sent a text to his friend‰Ûªs phone &lt;br /></classnote>
```

Saxon 9.5 PE outputs

```
Joe Smith '62 sent a text to his friend' phone
```

If you don't want to use XSLT 3.0 then the sample at least shows how to replace the substrings with a single quote: `replace(., '&amp;#39;|‰Ûªs', '''')`.